# try upload file with symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to upload a file with symfony. But I have an error when I send data formulaire to controller. Variable file is null and function move file don't working.

code entity (par uplaod):

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use AppBundle\Model\CompanyInterface;
    use AppBundle\Model\RecruiterInterface;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

    /**
     * Company.
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="company")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CompanyRepository")
     */
    class Company implements CompanyInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
         */
        private $name;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
         */
        private $description;

        /**
         * @var array
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="activities", type="array")
         */
        private $activities;

        /**
         * @var RecruiterInterface
         *
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Recruiter", cascade={"persist"})
         */
        private $recruiter;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255,nullable=true)
         */
        private $logo;

        /**
         * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
         */
        private $file;

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public static function create(string $name, RecruiterInterface $recruiter, string $description = '', array $activities = []): CompanyInterface
        {
            return new self($name, $recruiter, $description, $activities);
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function update(string $name, string $description, array $activities): CompanyInterface
        {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->description = $description;
            $this->activities = $activities;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function updateName(string $name): CompanyInterface
        {
            $this->name = $name;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getId(): string
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getName(): ?string
        {
            return $this->name;
        }

        /**
         * function setName.
         *
         * @param string $name
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function setName(string $name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * function setDescription.
         *
         * @param string $description
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function setDescription(string $description)
        {
            $this->description = $description;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * function setActivities.
         *
         * @param string $activities
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function setActivities(string $activities)
        {
            $this->activities = $activities;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getDescription(): ?string
        {
            return $this->description;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getActivities()
        {
            return $this->activities;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getRecruiter(): ?RecruiterInterface
        {
            return $this->recruiter;
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function __toString()
        {
            return $this->name;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function updateLogo(string $logo): CompanyInterface
        {
            $this->logo = $logo;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get file.
         *
         * @return UploadedFile
         */
        public function getFile()
        {
            return $this->file;
        }

        /**
         * Sets file.
         *
         * @param UploadedFile $file
         */
        public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
        {
            $this->file = $file;
        }

        /**
         * Set logo.
         *
         * @param string $logo
         *
         * @return Company
         */
        public function setLogo($logo)
        {
            $this->logo = $logo;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get logo.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getLogo()
        {
            return $this->logo;
        }

        /**
         * function upload.
         */
        public function upload()
        {
            // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
            if (null === $this->getFile()) {
                return;
            }
     $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(),$this->path);
            // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
            $this->logo = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();

            // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
            //$this->file = null;
        }

        /**
         * function getUploadRootDir.
         */
        protected function getUploadRootDir()
        {
            return __DIR__.'/../../../web/uploads';
        }
    }
```

code formType(content variable file):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

/**
 * Class CompanyType.
 */
class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('activities', TextType::class)
            ->add('file', FileType::class)
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Company',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

code other FormTyp(I use form imbrique):

```
    namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
    use AppBundle\Entity\Recruiter;

    /**
     * Class RecruiterType.
     */
    class RecruiterType extends AbstractType
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
            $builder->remove('username');
            $builder->remove('plainPassword');
            $builder
                ->add('email')
                ->add('lastname')
                ->add('firstname')
                ->add('phone')
                ->add('civility', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'choices' => ['Mr' => 'Mr', 'Mrs' => 'Mrs'], 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false,
                ))
                ->add('company', CompanyType::class)
                ;
        }

        /**
         * function get Parent Form.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getParent()
        {
            return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
        }

        /**
         * name for this form.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getBlockPrefix()
        {
            return '';
        }

        /**
         * name for this form.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->getBlockPrefix();
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => Recruiter::class,
                'allow_extra_fields' => true,
                'csrf_protection' => false,
            ));
        }
    }
```

function post (persist object):

```
public function post(array $parameters, bool $submitted = true, array $options = [])
        {
            /** @var Recruiter $recruiter */
            $recruiter = $this->formHandler->handle(
                $this->userManager->createRecruiter(),
                $parameters,
                Request::METHOD_POST,
                $submitted,
                $options
            );

            if (false === $submitted) {
                return $recruiter;
            }

            $recruiter->submit($parameters);

            if ($recruiter->isSubmitted() && $recruiter->isValid()) {
                $recruiter->getData()->setCompany($recruiter->getData()->getCompany());         
                $recruiter->getData()->getCompany()->upload();
                $this->em->persist($recruiter->getData());
                $this->em->flush();
                $event = new FormEvent($recruiter, $this->request);
                $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

                return $recruiter->getData();
            }

            return $recruiter;
        }
```

code controller :

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle\Controller\Recruiter;

    use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;
    use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
    use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
    use AppBundle\Handler\RecruiterHandler;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
    use AppBundle\Entity\Recruiter;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
    use AppBundle\Util\UserManagerr;

    /**
     * Class RegistrationRecruiterController.
     */
    class RegistrationRecruiterController extends BaseController
    {
        /**
         * @Template()
         * @Route("/register", name="register_recruiter")
         *
         * @param Request $request
         *
         * @return array|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
         */
        public function registerAction(Request $request)
        {
            try {
                $user = new UserManagerr();
                $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
                $user = $user->createRecruiter();

                $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

                if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
                    return $event->getResponse();
                }

                $recruiter = $this->getHandler()->post($request->request->all(), $request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST));

                if ($recruiter instanceof Recruiter) {
                    $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_check_email');
                    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

                    return $response;
                }
            } catch (InvalidFormException $e) {
                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

                return [
                    'form' => $e->getForm()->createView(),
                    'edit' => false,
                    'event' => $event->getResponse(),
                ];
            }

            return ['form' => $recruiter->createView()];
        }

        /**
         * @return RecruiterHandler
         */
        public function getHandler()
        {
            return $this->get(RecruiterHandler::class);
        }
    }
```

I use form imbriqu (form in other form) but when I send form I have all variable from object but variable file has null and function move doesn't work.

How to resolve this error please?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Help me please ...

Comment: It is quite hard to understand the code. Can you update it with the full namespace of the files? Can you please update the forms to have the full class?

Comment: @albert I update my answer and i add all code for entity and form

Comment: Add the controller as well

Comment: @albert I add code controller my friend

Comment: I've not found where and how you use your CompanyType anyway you have to submit the $request to the form not just the parameters. The file is not part of the parameters.

Comment: Function handle in post create form and I submit in ligne $recruiter->submit .. multiple variables has request but file only has null

Comment: Did you check the examples on how it works the symfony file upload? Because you will not have the file in the parameters bag, so it is normal that you do not have it

Comment: @albert , this is example in documentation symfony http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Comment: 1) Your example is not even remotely close to that. 2) You are passing the wrong object to the form as I mentioned before. 3) The cookbook is from symfony 2.0 which version of symfony do you use?

Comment: 1- version symfony is 3.3 , 2-the wrong object to the form as i metioned before!

Comment: Help me please ...

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
public function post(array $parameters, bool $submitted = true, array $options = [])
```

For

```
public function post(Request $request, bool $submitted = true, array $options = [])
[...]
$recruiter->submit($request);
[...]
```

Comment: $parameters is array and is $request->request->all();

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably in the for tag, which you should declare it like:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': '', 'attr': {'class': '', 'novalidate': 'novalidate' }}) }}
```